# How to call closure with closure as argument

Tags: rust

I have an struct that implements the trait `A` which has the function `fn consume`. I want to pass a callback to this struct, to be called by `fn consume`. Something like this:

`pub type OnVirtualTunWrite = Arc<dyn Fn(?, usize) -> Result<(), VirtualTunWriteError> + Send + Sync>;`

It's on an `Arc` because it's shared between threads.

```
struct A {
    on_virtual_tun_write: OnVirtualTunWrite
}

impl S for A {
    fn consume<R, F>(self, _timestamp: Instant, len: usize, f: F) -> smoltcp::Result<R>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> smoltcp::Result<R>,
    {
        let mut lower = self.lower.as_ref().borrow_mut();
        //I should send this f to self.on_virtual_tun_write
        (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(f, len);
        //return the appropriate result here
```

`OnVirtualTunWrite` is a closure that should receive the `f,len` from `fn consume` and then use it like this:

```
let my_on_virtual_tun_write = Arc::new(|?, len| -> ?{
    let mut buffer = Vec::new(len);
    buffer.resize(len);
    //fills buffer with data
    f(buffer);
})
```

How can I make my `OnVirtualTunWrite`?

I tried `Arc<dyn Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>` but it won't work because `dyn Fn` must have arguments with size know at compile time.

Also, there's still a small problem: how do I return `-> smoltcp::Result<R>` in `OnVirtualTunWrite` if `OnVirtualTunWrite` can't possibly know `R`?

Comment: Also does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577070/how-to-use-the-fn-traits-closures-in-rust-function-signatures

Comment: what about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618872/sized-is-not-implemented-for-the-type-fn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `Arc<dyn Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>`

That should be `&dyn FnOnce(...)`, but that won't work either because calling `FnOnce` automatically moves it, so it can't be called from behind a reference. The simplest solution is to introduce an extra allocation in `consume`, because `Box<dyn FnOnce>` implements `FnOnce` itself [since Rust 1.35](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-i-call-a-box-fnonce/778/4). For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da85b938ee4f5fd77662b9f4815861c9)):

```
pub type OnVirtualTunWrite = Arc<
    dyn Fn(Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8])>, usize) -> Result<(), VirtualTunWriteError> + Send + Sync,
>;

pub struct A {
    pub on_virtual_tun_write: OnVirtualTunWrite,
}

impl A {
    pub fn consume<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) + 'static,
    {
        (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(f), 0).unwrap();
    }
}
```

To avoid the allocation, you can use the technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40965033/1600898) to invoke `FnOnce` from an `FnMut`. It uses `Option` rather than `Box`, so it's zero-cost, or at least allocation-free. For example (full code [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0d721ccd781bbcb069b6316eaa71f98)):

```
pub type OnVirtualTunWrite = Arc<
    dyn Fn(&mut dyn FnMut(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), VirtualTunWriteError> + Send + Sync,
>;

trait CallOnceSafe {
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]);
}

impl<F: FnOnce(&mut [u8])> CallOnceSafe for Option<F> {
    fn call_once_safe(&mut self, x: &mut [u8]) {
        // panics if called more than once - but A::consume() calls it
        // only once
        let func = self.take().unwrap();
        func(x)
    }
}

impl A {
    pub fn consume<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) + 'static,
    {
        let mut f = Some(f);
        (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(&mut move |x| f.call_once_safe(x), 0).unwrap();
    }
}
```

The above works by first moving the `FnMut` into an `Option`, and calling it through `call_once_safe`, a method on a private `CallOnceSafe` trait with a blanket impl for `Option<T: FnOnce(...)>`. The blanket implementation moves the closure out of the `Option` and invokes it. This is allowed because the size of the closure is known in the blanket implementation, which is generic over `T`.

The blanket impl can get away with mutating rather than consuming `self` because it uses `Option::take` to move the content out of the option, while leaving it empty and otherwise usable. Not consuming the option allows `call_once_safe` to be called from an `FnMut` closure, such as the one created in `consume` and passed as argument to `OnVirtualTunWrite`. `call_once_safe` does consume the actual `FnOnce` closure contained in the `Option`, thus preserving the invariant that the closure is called no more than once. If `consume` were to call `call_once_safe` on the same `Option<F>` twice (or if the outer closure called its first argument more than once), it would result in a panic.

Comment: Thanks, very good workaround to prevent Box allocation. However, your consume ignores the `<R>` generic. I'm forced to use it in the trait implementation. And I don't know how to use the return type from `f`, which is `smoltcp::Result<R>`, in its caller, which is `OnVirtualTunWrite`

Comment: @Gatonito Can `OnVirtualTunWrite` and `A` be generic over `R`? I really don't see how it could work otherwise.

Comment: That would force the struct that holds the `OnVirtualTunWrite` to be generic over R too, rigth? I'm thinking of a way out of this. Maybe return a generic Ok(R) if ok and Err(R) if not, but I think even this is not possible, as R might not be default constructible?

Comment: I thought of something like this: `let r;
        let result = (lower.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
            r = f(b);
        }), len);` but it appears that I cannot modify the outside `r` from the Box closure

Comment: @Gatonito Yes, both the closure and `A` need to be generic over `R`, I don't see a way around that - given the lack of any trait bounds on `R` (no `Default`, no `From`) there is no way you could invent your own `R` value inside `consume`. You could return an `Err(smoltcp::Error(Exhausted))` or something, and it would compile, but it's unlikely to work correctly. I'm not sure where you're going with `let r`, but perhaps that will work if you make the closure `move`.